# Systemd user unit depends of system target

Tags: system, systemd

I am writing several `systemd user` units and some of them need to depend on the `system` unit `wpa_supplicant@INT.service`. These units need to be started when the `wpa_supplicant@INT.service` starts and stop when it stops.

I have seen that `user` units can not depend on `system` units. So, how can I do that ?

Do I have to rewrite all my user units at system units ? Seems very disgraceful and not the way to go.

I would like to avoid creating a service that will check the state of the `wpa_supplicant@INT.service` and would like to be alerted directly by an instance of systemd.

Any advice will be very appreciated,

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found two ways to do that.

We can use systemctl from the system to talk to the user systemctl instance with the `--user --machine=user@.host` argument.

For example, in a systemd system unit we can start a process like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "systemctl --user --machine=$${USER}@.host stop wpa_service.target"
```

Another way is to use a socket to talk to a service running at the user level. Then it will perform any actions at the user session level without any problem.